# What kind of information is stored on the PVC's for Harbor?

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm, appharbor, persistent-volume-claims, harbor

There is no information within Harbor's documentation about the kind of data that is stored within the persistent volume claim's for Harbor. Is anyone aware of what's being stored on there?

Looked all over the internet as well as Harbors documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since Harbor is using multiple PVCs and you didn't specify which PVCs you mean I am going to list all.

Btw. the [Harbor Helm Chart](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm/#:%7E:text=persistence.persistentVolumeClaim) has pritty good description of all the PVcS

1. **jobservice** - Execution logs of jobs, like replication, GC, vulnerability scanner, and more.
2. **database** - all the data you see when interacting with the UI. Depending on the config also joblogs. Container images are never stored in the DB
3. **redis** - Caching data, also cron job schedule. But the schedule is synchronized with the db (since v2.4 or so). Redis can be set up ephemeral.
4. **trivy** – the vulnerability database, contains all vulnerability data. It can be set up ephemeral if you don't mind downloading 80MiB on each Pod restart.
5. **persistence.imageChartStorage.type** – If it is set to `filesystem` then in this PVC the images are stored.

These are all the PVCs where data is stored.